# SSRS - Refine WHERE Criteria in T-SQL Query

Tags: t-sql, parameters, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am developing a report that should return results depending on user-specified parameters. There are 3 report parameters, one is a drop down with 'Locations', and the other two are text parameters to search within 'user_id' and users' first or last name.  This is what I am currently using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserTable1
WHERE Location = @Location
AND (user_id LIKE '%'+@SearchUserID+'%'
AND first_name LIKE '%'+@SearchUserName+'%' 
OR last_name LIKE '%'+@SearchUserName+'%')
```

If the @SearchUserID parameter field is left blank by the user, all user_ids should be returned (that meet the other 2 parameters).  If specified, it will return user_ids that have that substring in the user_id.  Same thing goes for the @SearchUserName parameter field. If left blank, it should return all users that meet the other parameters.  If specified, it should return all users that have that substring in their first_name or last_name (but only results that meet the other parameters).  If both are left blank, it should return all users.

The query I have above is not working.  It seems to just return results meeting the @SearchUserName parameter, but disregards the @SearchUserID parameter.  Is there a way to fix this?  I had put the @SearchUserID filter on the tablix itself, using the expression:
    ="*" & Parameters!SearchUserID.Value & "*"
But this has resulted in severely hampered performance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You must pass `NULL` if parameter is blank(empty).

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserTable1
WHERE Location = @Location
AND (user_id LIKE '%'+@SearchUserID+'%'
       OR @SearchUserID IS NULL
    )
AND (first_name LIKE '%'+@SearchUserName+'%'
       OR last_name LIKE '%'+@SearchUserName+'%'
       OR @SearchUserName IS NULL
    )
```

"....but disregards the @SearchUserID parameter." What data type of `user_id`?

Comment: Thanks Hamlet, that worked perfectly. The fields were varchars.